# Laptop + 2 Displays Issue

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-graphics-card, external-display, intel-graphics, optimus

I'd like to extend the display of my ASUS N53SV-SZ038V to two external monitors.

The laptop has one HDMI output and one VGA output. I have each connected to an external monitor. The problem is that it only allows two displays to show at a time (either laptop display + 1 monitor or 2 monitors). This is highlighted below:

[image: Display Settings]

The laptop has integrated Intel HD Graphics 3000 on the i7-2630QM as well as an NVIDIA GT540M. Whilst I don't think that either can support 3 displays directly, I was hoping that I might be able to offload one of the displays (or more) onto the graphics card.

After going into the NVIDIA control panel, I saw the below and thought there might be a way to rearrange it, but it appears not:

[image: NVIDIA Control Panel]

It would be much appreciated if someone could provide some guidance on whether or not this can be achieved, or indeed any other suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your laptop Graphics card is limited to 2 displays you may want to look in to a [usb to vga adapter](http://www.tigerdirect.ca/applications/category/category_slc.asp?CatId=467&name=Monitor%20Adapter) You won't get great performance game / HD video wise on that display, but it will do the trick for web/e-mail/chat.

Comment: This is the solution that I ended up using in the end.

In case anyone is wondering, I am using the [Kensington Multi-Display Adapter](http://www.kensington.com/kensington/us/us/p/1422/K33928US/universal-multi-display-adapter.aspx).

Everything seems to function as normal and the 3rd monitor appears in the Display settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to display on three screens at the same time, you'll need a video card that will support that.  Video cards are, ultimately, what support just about everything to do with your display, from the pixel rating to the refresh rate to the number of potential displays.  You may want to check this page out, here:

http://www.popularmechanics.com/technology/how-to/tips/how-to-set-up-multiple-monitors

However, while I'm not terribly familiar with laptop video cards, I'm not sure if yours will actually support multiple displays (as in more than two at a time), or it would probably have put it as an option.

Alternatively, however, you could try checking out your Nvidia Settings, as there are often options there that are not available through the Windows interface.

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop has both an integrated video card `Intel HD Graphics 3000` as well as a dedicated video card `NVIDIA GT540M`. Both of those cards most likely support the use of two monitors each.

Unfortunately there is no way for both of them to work together at the same time. To do so would require a technology like `AMD/ATI's Crossfire` or `Nvidia's SLI`.

What you can do though if your jonesing for three monitors is set up another machine and link them all together with free software like this: http://synergy-foss.org/  so that they act like one single computer.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for clarifying; I had a feeling that this might be the issue. It seems that, rather unfortunately, my GPU is not supported.

Comment: Unfortunately most laptops don't. Glad I could help.