# Three monitor display

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I am now having a double monitor display. My laptop is connected to two external monitors. The first one over HDMI and the second one over VGA. Can I somehowe active also the laptoop screen so that I can have a 3 monitor display.

Is this possible?

Laptop Dell Inspiron 7720
OS: windows 7
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 4000

[image]

Comment: Is there anything in wondows default monitor options preventing you to do so ? (if using another OS, please specify which, and your GPU brand)

Comment: Well, it depends, as Kwaio said, about your set up... Can your mobo/GPU support this? What laptop, what OS, what GPU, internal or external drive, any mods etc?

Comment: Laptop Dell Inspiron 7720
Os: windows 7
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 4000

Comment: Would you be able to upload and add a screenshot of the menu : "Control Panel > Display > Screen Resolution" ? (after clicking on "detect" to be sure all plugged monitors are detected)

Comment: possible additional leads from : http://superuser.com/questions/441249/laptop-2-displays-issue

Answer (score 6):

> Technically the 17R SE 7720 itself will allow up to 3 monitors
>   (Built-in Display and 2 External Displays) to be connected in either
>   Clone or Extended Mode and working all at once.

However, and this is the important part:

> Without using Intel's WiDi technology (Drivers are available for the 17R SE 7720 in the Dell Driver Download Section) you'll be limited to using only 2 displays.

There are also suggestions about using a splitter, but, this (from my understanding) will  duplicate the content where as I assume you want to use 3 monitors individually with unique content).

[Source and more reading (recommended)](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19492624.aspx)

Also, check out http://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-HD-Graphics-4000.69168.0.html as this claims the Intel HD Graphics 4000 has the ability:

> Another new feature is the support for up to 3 independent displays (depends on how the HD 4000 is used in the laptop - maybe only with a DisplayPort / eDP) as AMD offers with theirs Eyefinity support (up to 6 displays).